# Cosa sono i "risvolti a cuneo" in un vestito?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Qualunque mestiere faccia, Rocco guadagna meglio di prima, perché s’è appena rifatto il guardaroba (tre vestiti nuovi, tutti neri, con le righe e i **risvolti a cuneo**), ha regalato un mucchio di 78 giri a Lena, un rasoio con l’impugnatura di osso a Coca-cola, un collare coi campanellini d’argento al suo gatto e una bambola parlante a Vita, un vero prodigio meccanico che muggisce parole come *Mamy, Daddy, I love you*, e via dicendo, e stavolta non l’ha rubata perché era ancora avvolta nella carta del negozio.

Sapreste spiegarmi cosa sono questi "risvolti a cuneo" che avevano i vestiti di Rocco? Ho cercato il termine "cuneo" in parecchi dizionari, ma non riesco a immaginare in che cosa consistono tali risvolti di un vestito.

Comment: In che anni si svolge la scena? Sapendolo si può guardare la moda maschile del tempo; in genere, "a cuneo" mi fa pensare che presentino una piega ad angolo netta

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Si svolge a New York nei primi anni del Novecento.

Comment: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3c/92/b3/3c92b302b5b092cc351cfc436d1d60dd.png il primo da sinistra ha una giacca il cui bavero presenta dei "cunei" verso l'alto; cfr anche http://bloshka.info/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/20_mode-1900-2.jpg (il quarto da sinistra). Potrebbe trattarsi di questo?

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: [Qui](http://www.thebespokedudes.com/it/artigiani/646/the-spanish-chapter-sastreria-serna) si parla di giacche maschili che hanno un "bavero spiovente", che "non hanno riprese fino al fondo e non presentano cunei sotto il bavero".

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Quindi, si tratta forse di qualche tessuto posto sotto il bavero per rialzarlo?

Comment: Non saprei... io pensavo a una cosa di questo tipo https://img.mytheresa.com/1088/1088/66/jpeg/catalog/product/39/P00336314.jpg (anche se questa è moderna)

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Ho visto che questo si chiama ["rever (oppure risvolto o bavero) a lancia"](http://www.ilblogdelmarchese.com/revers-della-giacca/).

Comment: Vedi anche [qui](https://www.lanieri.com/blog/it/le-misure-delleleganza-baveri-e-colli/).

Comment: mah... non saprei cosa aggiungere.